# Android won't connect to RasPi access point

Tags: android, access-point, systemd-networkd, wpa-supplicant

I have managed to turn my Raspberry Pi into an access point following these instructions:

[Access point as WiFi router/repeater with additional WiFi-dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95072/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-with-additional-wifi-dongle/95073#95073)

However, everything connects to the access point except my android devices (A Samsung Galaxy Note 8 and a Samsung Galaxy S5).

A similar problem is presented in this question:

[Android cannot connect to Pi's wlan](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/93660/android-cannot-connect-to-pis-wlan)

However, the answer given there does not apply to me since I have the file `/etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network` exactly as in the first link. (hence with DHCP server activated):

```
[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
Address=192.168.4.1/24
IPForward=yes
DHCPServer=yes
[DHCPServer]
DNS=84.200.69.80 1.1.1.1
```

How can I fix it?

## Further information:

### Problem Description

Both my devices can see the network.
The Galaxy Note 8 keeps trying to connect, when I insert the password it says "Connecting..." under the SSID for approximately 3 seconds stops showing the message for 2 seconds and then keeps trying to connect.
Almost the same with the Galaxy S5 with the difference that it also writes "Obtaining IP address" before stopping and then keeps retrying.

### Check on DHCP (as apparently is a known issue, see the second link)

Journalctl does not seem to show DHCP requests, hence I have extended the log as described here:

https://superuser.com/questions/1187633/how-to-debug-systemd-networkd

Launching `journalctl -b -u systemd-networkd`, I have tried to reconnect several times with my android devices From 12:16 on, however, I see only two DHCP server requests.

```
Jan 11 12:14:28 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[855]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesCh
Jan 11 12:16:04 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[855]: DHCP SERVER: REQUEST (rebinding/renewing) (0x4f98fb1a)
Jan 11 12:16:04 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[855]: DHCP SERVER: ACK (0x4f98fb1a)
Jan 11 12:17:39 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[855]: DHCP SERVER: REQUEST (rebinding/renewing) (0x26d7c444)
Jan 11 12:17:39 raspberrypi systemd-networkd[855]: DHCP SERVER: ACK (0x26d7c444)
```

### Check on wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service

I get

```
root@raspberrypi:~ # journalctl -b -u wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service 
-- Logs begin at Sat 2020-01-11 10:03:13 CST, end at Sat 2020-01-11 12:28:44 CST. --
Jan 11 10:03:16 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version).
Jan 11 10:03:17 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Jan 11 10:03:17 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
Jan 11 10:03:21 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: Could not connect to kernel driver
Jan 11 10:03:21 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: Using interface wlan0 with hwaddr **DeviceMac** and ssid "**Device_SSID**"
Jan 11 10:03:21 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->ENABLED
Jan 11 10:03:21 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: AP-ENABLED
Jan 11 10:03:21 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to **DeviceMac** completed [id=0 id_str=]
Jan 11 10:04:47 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 10:04:47 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED **MAC_OF_PC1**
Jan 11 10:05:12 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 10:05:12 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED **MAC_OF_PC2**
Jan 11 10:05:19 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jan 11 10:05:19 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
Jan 11 10:06:06 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 10:06:14 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 10:06:21 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 11:04:32 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Jan 11 11:04:33 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=US
Jan 11 11:13:47 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 11:13:55 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:16:25 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:16:32 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:16:32 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:16:48 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:16:55 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:17:03 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:17:15 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:18:17 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:18:25 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:18:33 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:18:41 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:18:49 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:18:57 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:19:05 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:19:13 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:20:15 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:20:23 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:20:31 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:28:22 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:28:29 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:28:37 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 11 12:28:44 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
```

At least I see the connection attempts at their right times as `CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0`.

I have also tried to submit a wrong password, in this case I get:

```
Jan 11 12:37:12 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: AP-STA-POSSIBLE-PSK-MISMATCH **PhoneAddress**
Jan 11 12:37:13 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: AP-STA-POSSIBLE-PSK-MISMATCH **PhoneAddress**
Jan 11 12:37:14 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: AP-STA-POSSIBLE-PSK-MISMATCH **PhoneAddress**
Jan 11 12:37:15 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[352]: wlan0: AP-STA-POSSIBLE-PSK-MISMATCH **PhoneAddress**
```

### Ipv6?

I found out that in order to download updates faster it was convenient to switch off RasPi Ipv6. Could this interfere? I had this doubt since when I connected to the network from a Windows machine I found out in the WiFi properties that there is a Link-local IPv6 address. Since it is often claimed that Link-local is what is not supported in android, it might be that the Ipv6 settings are necessary for android to connect to a wifi network. But how to switch on IPv6 and set DHCP inside systemd-networkd?

However from this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978595/what-triggers-assigning-ipv6-link-local-address-in-android

I deduce that android devices are capable of getting a link-local Ipv6 address.

### Another similar question

[Access Point not working for Android phones](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90008/access-point-not-working-for-android-phones)

But the answers do not make sense to me.

I have tried to change `/etc/systemd/network/08-wlan0.network` to

```
[Match]
Name=wlan0
[Network]
Address=10.10.11.1/24
IPForward=yes
DHCPServer=yes
[DHCPServer]
DNS=84.200.69.80 1.1.1.1
```

then from `ifconfig` on my laptop I get:

```
wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.11.72  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.10.11.255
        inet6 fe80::aeee:ee4:1a78:6517  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether **MACADDRESS**  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 15397  bytes 8998330 (8.9 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9034  bytes 2177688 (2.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And still can not connect from mobile.
I also changed it to `Address=192.168.0.0/24` and I couldn't connect this time also from the pcs, however from `journalctl -b -u wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service` I got a different error from the pcs and the from the android devices (and the error given to the android devices is the same old one).

```
Jan 12 09:33:43 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[359]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 12 09:33:47 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[359]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 12 09:33:51 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[359]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 12 09:34:07 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[359]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 12 09:34:11 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[359]: wlan0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED f8:54:b8:85:45:01
Jan 12 09:34:16 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[359]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 12 09:34:25 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[359]: wlan0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED 60:14:b3:6d:a0:af
Jan 12 09:34:26 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[359]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Jan 12 09:34:26 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[359]: wlan0: AP-STA-CONNECTED 60:14:b3:6d:a0:af
Jan 12 09:35:11 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[359]: wlan0: AP-STA-DISCONNECTED 60:14:b3:6d:a0:af
```

### Debugging from Android

Thanks to `adb shell` I was able to launch `dumpsys wifi` on my galaxy S5, and I got

Working connection

```
01-12 14:16:22.185 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=33 state=6 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00 SSID=**PhoneNetwork**]
01-12 14:16:22.185 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 Associated with **PhoneHotspotMAC**]
01-12 14:16:22.211 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=33 state=7 BSSID=**PhoneHotspotMAC** SSID=**PhoneNetwork**]
01-12 14:16:22.211 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 WPA: RX message 1 of 4-Way Handshake from 6E.3F.F0 (ver=2)]
01-12 14:16:22.212 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 WPA: Sending EAPOL-Key 2/4]
01-12 14:16:22.231 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 WPA: RX message 3 of 4-Way Handshake from 6E.3F.F0 (ver=2)]
01-12 14:16:22.233 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 WPA: Sending EAPOL-Key 4/4]
01-12 14:16:22.234 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=33 state=8 BSSID=**PhoneHotspotMAC** SSID=**PhoneNetwork**]
01-12 14:16:22.235 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 WPA: Key negotiation completed with **PhoneHotspotMAC** [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]]
01-12 14:16:22.235 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to **PhoneHotspotMAC** completed [id=33 id_str=]]
01-12 14:16:22.236 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=33 state=9 BSSID=**PhoneHotspotMAC** SSID=**PhoneNetwork**]
01-12 14:16:22.242 - wlan0: 4486:IFNAME=wlan0 GET FREQUENCY -> 2457
01-12 14:16:22.242 - wlan0: 4487:IFNAME=wlan0 SET_NETWORK 33 verified_password 1 -> true
01-12 14:16:22.251 - wlan0: 4488:IFNAME=wlan0 SAVE_CONFIG -> true
01-12 14:16:22.255 - wlan0: 4489:IFNAME=wlan0 SET pno 0 -> true
01-12 14:16:22.277 - wlan0: 4490:IFNAME=wlan0 PKTCNT_POLL -> TXGOOD=26571
TXBAD=508
RXGOOD=753
01-12 14:16:22.360 - wlan0: 4491:IFNAME=wlan0 DRIVER BTCOEXMODE 1 -> true
01-12 14:16:22.365 - wlan0: 4492:IFNAME=wlan0 DRIVER SETSUSPENDMODE 0 -> true
01-12 14:16:22.366 - wlan0: 4493:IFNAME=wlan0 SET ps 0 -> true
01-12 14:16:22.383 - wlan0: 4494:IFNAME=wlan0 LIST_NETWORKS -> network id / ssid / bssid / flags
```

Not working connection

```
01-12 14:16:59.083 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=32 state=6 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00 SSID=**RasPiNetwork**]
01-12 14:16:59.084 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 Associated with **RasPiMAC**]
01-12 14:16:59.084 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=32 state=7 BSSID=**RasPiMAC** SSID=**RasPiNetwork**]
01-12 14:16:59.085 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 WPA: RX message 1 of 4-Way Handshake from DC.FF.96 (ver=2)]
01-12 14:16:59.086 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 WPA: Sending EAPOL-Key 2/4]
01-12 14:16:59.093 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 WPA: RX message 3 of 4-Way Handshake from DC.FF.96 (ver=2)]
01-12 14:16:59.095 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 WPA: Sending EAPOL-Key 4/4]
01-12 14:16:59.095 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=32 state=8 BSSID=**RasPiMAC** SSID=**RasPiNetwork**]
01-12 14:17:03.112 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 CTRL-EVENT-BIGDATA-DISCONNECT 2 36 1 2 dc:a6:32 2462 20 -40 72 2 0 x x 0 -92 0 0]
01-12 14:17:03.112 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=**RasPiMAC** reason=2]
01-12 14:17:03.113 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=32 state=0 BSSID=**RasPiMAC** SSID=**RasPiNetwork**]
01-12 14:17:03.212 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=-1 state=3 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00 SSID=]
01-12 14:17:03.219 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED ]
01-12 14:17:05.402 - wlan0: 4581:IFNAME=wlan0 SET pno 0 -> true
01-12 14:17:05.404 - wlan0: 4582:IFNAME=wlan0 SCAN -> false
01-12 14:17:06.984 - wlan0: 4583:IFNAME=wlan0 SET pno 0 -> true
01-12 14:17:06.985 - wlan0: 4584:IFNAME=wlan0 SCAN -> false
01-12 14:17:07.024 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS ]
01-12 14:17:07.024 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 WPS-AP-AVAILABLE ]
01-12 14:17:07.043 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 Trying to associate with **RasPiMAC** (SSID='**RasPiNetwork**' freq=2462 MHz level=-38) ]
01-12 14:17:07.046 - Event [IFNAME=wlan0 CTRL-EVENT-STATE-CHANGE id=32 state=5 BSSID=00:00:00:00:00:00 SSID=**RasPiNetwork**]
01-12 14:17:07.077 - wlan0: 4585:IFNAME=wlan0 LIST_NETWORKS -> network id / ssid / bssid / flags
```

Apparently `(reason = 2)` (https://www.cisco.com/assets/sol/sb/WAP371_Emulators/WAP371_Emulator_v1-0-1-5/help/Apx_ReasonCodes2.html) stands for "Previous authentication no longer valid".

## Possible Path to a solution

From here

https://community.ui.com/questions/Android-devices-always-disconnecting-on-AP-AC-Pro/8512e697-1720-43b0-b0ee-591686b7f458?page=1

I got that "So somehow, having Multicast / Broadcast on my network kicks my Android devices". I don't even know how to check if my hotspot has those or can avoid those.

Here this multicast issue is vaguely addressed:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221736/android-device-not-receiving-multicast-package

In particular the comment "This page has a wealth of information about which IP to use as per your needs. " reminds me of a similar comment in an answer at the link under the section "another similar question" however the link does not seem to help.

Launching `systemd-resolve --status` I get

```
Link 4 (wlan0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes
```

However, I still can not connect from my smartphones.

### Final Attempt

I have tried to do the whole process again, burning the image on an SD card and so on. Without the net forwarding but only with the access point with systemd... I confirm that android devices can not connect to it. It is incredible that it looks like I am the only one worried about this problem!

### For the joy of a commenter

For the joy of a commenter I am posting the result of the following command

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iw wlan0
```

The result is incredibly long and I personally doubt that it works with systemd-networkd.
Here it is: https://pastebin.com/h6r46mB8

## Serious debugging

After launching `sudo /sbin/wpa_supplicant -d -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf -Dnl80211,wext -iwlan0` I got

https://pastebin.com/nBkm3SNx

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103271/discussion-on-question-by-thepunisher-android-wont-connect-to-raspi-access-poin).

Comment: What Raspberry Pi version do you use? Is it a RPi 4B?

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the setup with a Huawai smartphone Android version 4.0.3 and a FAIRPHONE Android version 9. Both phones connected without any problems so it is difficult for me to debug an error that isn't present. Here are some ideas:

From your tests the problem seems to be WiFi asoziation, the step before getting an ip address. So you should focus on wpa_supplicant. The first test could be to explecitely define the encryption method. This was in the past **WPA** but nowadays improved to **WPA2** or also named **RSN**. But **WPA** is sometimes still used. Check with both settings. In `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf` add the option `proto=RSN WPA` (will first use RSN then WPA) and both single settings. Have also an attention to your correct `country=` setting so it looks similar to this:

```
rpi ~$ sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=nn

network={
    ssid="RPiNet"
    mode=2
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    proto=RSN WPA
    # proto=RSN
    # proto=WPA
    psk="verySecretPassword"
    frequency=2412
}
```

If this doesn't help then use a very simple stand alone access point with latest configuration updates to reduce side effects. Setup it as shown in [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866) in section **♦ Setting up a stand alone access point**.

After a fresh flashed Raspbian Buster image and update/full-upgrade you should first do `sudo apt install tcpdump`. Maybe you will look at the traffic on the interfaces. Later you don't have an internet connection for installations. After setup you should add option `DNSSEC=no` to `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and reboot to disable DNS record signing. There is a known bug as shown in [Sporadic "DNSSEC validation failed" — "no-signature" #12388](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/12388).

Now try connecting your Android phones. If it fails then start wpa_supplicant in foreground debug mode and inspect its output.

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
rpi ~$ sudo /sbin/wpa_supplicant -d -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan0.conf -Dnl80211,wext -iwlan0
```

If wpa_supplicant has started with a bunch of detailed low level messages, then try to connect a phone. Take time for inspecting the verbose output from the connection attempt, look for failing messages and it lines before.

**UPDATE** with comparing the debug output from wpa_supplicant:
I have reactivated my old SAMSUNG GALAXY S II with Android 4.1.2. It also connects without any problems. Here are the part of your wpa_supplicant debug output where it differs from mine:

```
hostapd_logger: STA 6c:c7:ec:4c:3f:f0 - sending 3/4 msg of 4-Way Handshake
WPA: Send EAPOL(version=2 secure=0 mic=1 ack=1 install=1 pairwise=1 kde_len=28 keyidx=0 encr=0)
WPA: Replay Counter - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02
WPA: EAPOL-Key MIC using HMAC-SHA1
WPA: Use EAPOL-Key timeout of 1000 ms (retry counter 1)
hostapd_logger: STA 6c:c7:ec:4c:3f:f0 - EAPOL-Key timeout
WPA: 6c:c7:ec:4c:3f:f0 WPA_PTK entering state PTKINITNEGOTIATING
hostapd_logger: STA 6c:c7:ec:4c:3f:f0 - sending 3/4 msg of 4-Way Handshake
WPA: Send EAPOL(version=2 secure=0 mic=1 ack=1 install=1 pairwise=1 kde_len=28 keyidx=0 encr=0)
WPA: Replay Counter - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03
WPA: EAPOL-Key MIC using HMAC-SHA1
WPA: Use EAPOL-Key timeout of 1000 ms (retry counter 2)
hostapd_logger: STA 6c:c7:ec:4c:3f:f0 - EAPOL-Key timeout
WPA: 6c:c7:ec:4c:3f:f0 WPA_PTK entering state PTKINITNEGOTIATING
hostapd_logger: STA 6c:c7:ec:4c:3f:f0 - sending 3/4 msg of 4-Way Handshake
WPA: Send EAPOL(version=2 secure=0 mic=1 ack=1 install=1 pairwise=1 kde_len=28 keyidx=0 encr=0)
WPA: Replay Counter - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04
WPA: EAPOL-Key MIC using HMAC-SHA1
WPA: Use EAPOL-Key timeout of 1000 ms (retry counter 3)
hostapd_logger: STA 6c:c7:ec:4c:3f:f0 - EAPOL-Key timeout
WPA: 6c:c7:ec:4c:3f:f0 WPA_PTK entering state PTKINITNEGOTIATING
hostapd_logger: STA 6c:c7:ec:4c:3f:f0 - sending 3/4 msg of 4-Way Handshake
WPA: Send EAPOL(version=2 secure=0 mic=1 ack=1 install=1 pairwise=1 kde_len=28 keyidx=0 encr=0)
WPA: Replay Counter - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05
WPA: EAPOL-Key MIC using HMAC-SHA1
WPA: Use EAPOL-Key timeout of 1000 ms (retry counter 4)
hostapd_logger: STA 6c:c7:ec:4c:3f:f0 - EAPOL-Key timeout
WPA: 6c:c7:ec:4c:3f:f0 WPA_PTK entering state PTKINITNEGOTIATING
hostapd_logger: STA 6c:c7:ec:4c:3f:f0 - PTKINITNEGOTIATING: Retry limit 4 reached
WPA: 6c:c7:ec:4c:3f:f0 WPA_PTK entering state DISCONNECT
```

But from my GALAXY S II it should look like this:

```
hostapd_logger: STA 98:0c:82:ba:7a:aa - sending 3/4 msg of 4-Way Handshake
WPA: Send EAPOL(version=2 secure=0 mic=1 ack=1 install=1 pairwise=1 kde_len=28 keyidx=0 encr=0)
WPA: Replay Counter - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02
WPA: EAPOL-Key MIC using HMAC-SHA1
WPA: Use EAPOL-Key timeout of 1000 ms (retry counter 1)
l2_packet_receive: src=98:0c:82:ba:7a:aa len=99
wlan0: RX EAPOL from 98:0c:82:ba:7a:aa
IEEE 802.1X: 99 bytes from 98:0c:82:ba:7a:aa
   IEEE 802.1X: version=1 type=3 length=95
WPA: Received EAPOL-Key from 98:0c:82:ba:7a:aa key_info=0x10a type=254 mic_len=16 key_data_length=0
WPA: Received Key Nonce - hexdump(len=32): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
WPA: Received Replay Counter - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02
hostapd_logger: STA 98:0c:82:ba:7a:aa - received EAPOL-Key frame (4/4 Pairwise)
WPA: EAPOL-Key MIC using HMAC-SHA1
WPA: 98:0c:82:ba:7a:aa WPA_PTK entering state PTKINITDONE
```

Until step 3 of the 4-Way Handshake there is no difference but then receiving an EAPOL-Key timed out on your RasPi. It retried 4 times and then entered state DISCONNECT, never reaching state PTKINITDONE. Timeout is set to 1000 ms. I have looked at `/usr/share/doc/wpa_supplicant/examples/wpa_supplicant.conf` and asked google if there is a way to increase this timeout without success. All what I have found was that this could be a driver problem so an idea was to use the older **wext** driver but this doesn't support AP mode (mode=2). I don't really belief it's a hardware or firmware problem. I guess it is an issue with an app or driver that you only run on your android devices. Have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you! I have modified wpa_supplicant as you suggested and I copied the log.

Do you think that it might be a Samsung issue?
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1647184

Comment: @ThePunisher Don't know. I have an old Samsung Galaxy II. I will test with it, just a moment please ...

Comment: @ThePunisher I have updated the question for some time.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up here with the same issue.

After some Googling + trial and error, was able to resolve the issue by upgrading `wpa supplicant` to v2.9 by building it manually using the follow config (source https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1647184#c2):

```
CONFIG_TLS=internal
CONFIG_INTERNAL_LIBTOMMATH=y
CONFIG_INTERNAL_LIBTOMMATH_FAST=y

CONFIG_IEEE8021X_EAPOL=y

CONFIG_ERP=y
CONFIG_EAP_MD5=y
CONFIG_MSCHAPV2=y
CONFIG_EAP_TLS=y
CONFIG_EAP_PEAP=y
CONFIG_EAP_TTLS=y
CONFIG_EAP_GTC=y
CONFIG_EAP_OTP=y
CONFIG_EAP_PSK=y
CONFIG_EAP_PAX=y
CONFIG_EAP_LEAP=y
CONFIG_EAP_SIM=y
CONFIG_EAP_AKA=y
CONFIG_EAP_AKA_PRIME=y
CONFIG_EAP_VENDOR_TEST=y
CONFIG_EAP_TLV=y
CONFIG_EAP_SAKE=y
CONFIG_EAP_GPSK=y
CONFIG_EAP_GPSK_SHA256=y
CONFIG_EAP_EKE=y
CONFIG_EAP_TNC=y
CFLAGS += -DTNC_CONFIG_FILE=\"tnc/tnc_config\"
LIBS += -rdynamic
CONFIG_EAP_FAST=y
CONFIG_EAP_IKEV2=y

CONFIG_IPV6=y
CONFIG_DRIVER_NONE=y
CONFIG_PKCS12=y
CONFIG_CTRL_IFACE=unix

CONFIG_WPA_CLI_EDIT=y

CONFIG_OCSP=y

#CONFIG_ELOOP_POLL=y

CONFIG_CTRL_IFACE_DBUS_NEW=y
CONFIG_CTRL_IFACE_DBUS_INTRO=y

CONFIG_IEEE80211W=y
CONFIG_IEEE80211R=y
CONFIG_IEEE80211N=y
CONFIG_IEEE80211AC=y

CONFIG_DEBUG_FILE=y

CONFIG_WPS=y
#CONFIG_WPS_STRICT=y
CONFIG_WPS_UPNP=y
CONFIG_WPS_NFC=y
CONFIG_WPS_ER=y
#CONFIG_WPS_REG_DISABLE_OPEN=y

CONFIG_DRIVER_WEXT=y

CONFIG_DRIVER_NL80211=y
CFLAGS += -I/usr/include/libnl3
CONFIG_LIBNL32=y

CONFIG_IBSS_RSN=y

CONFIG_AP=y
#CONFIG_MESH=y
CONFIG_P2P=y
CONFIG_WIFI_DISPLAY=y

CONFIG_ACS=y

CONFIG_BGSCAN_SIMPLE=y
CONFIG_BGSCAN_LEARN=y

#CONFIG_WPA_TRACE=y
#CONFIG_WPA_TRACE_BFD=y

CONFIG_TDLS=y
#CONFIG_TDLS_TESTING=y
CONFIG_NO_RANDOM_POOL=y

CONFIG_TLSV11=y
CONFIG_TLSV12=y

#CONFIG_HT_OVERRIDES=y
#CONFIG_VHT_OVERRIDES=y

#CONFIG_DEBUG_LINUX_TRACING=y

CONFIG_INTERWORKING=y
CONFIG_HS20=y

CONFIG_AUTOSCAN_EXPONENTIAL=y
CONFIG_AUTOSCAN_PERIODIC=y

CONFIG_EXT_PASSWORD_TEST=y

CONFIG_EAP_UNAUTH_TLS=y

#CONFIG_SAE=y
#CFLAGS += -DALL_DH_GROUPS

CONFIG_WNM=y

CONFIG_FST=y
#CONFIG_FST_TEST=y

#CONFIG_TESTING_OPTIONS=y
#CONFIG_MODULE_TESTS=y

CONFIG_SUITEB=y

CONFIG_MBO=y

#CONFIG_CODE_COVERAGE=y
CFLAGS += -O0 -Wsign-compare
#CONFIG_FILS=y
#CONFIG_FILS_SK_PFS=y
CONFIG_PMKSA_CACHE_EXTERNAL=y
#CONFIG_OWE=y
#CONFIG_DPP=y

CONFIG_DEBUG_SYSLOG=y
```